# jump to root (su -) with google authentication for one specific user

Tags: linux, pam, google-authenticator

in my test servers (with debian or centos) I need to be able to jump from only once user to root with google authentication.
to understand the problem, for example on the server I have two users
bob -> to use su - or su root uses google authentication (does not know and can not knows root password)
alice -> to use su - or su root using normal root password because he knows them.
I do not know if I understand correctly, I try to add it to 

`[root@proxy ~]# nano /etc/pam.d/su`

lines on top such as:

```
#%PAM-1.0
#auth required pam_google_authenticator.so nullok use_uid user = bob
#auth required pam_google_authenticator.so use_uid user = bob
auth required pam_google_authenticator.so
```

but nothing of conditions `user = bob` not working. Only the standard "global" row works fine... I tested it with many guides from the web
but it still does not work. I have no ideas how to solve this problem.

I am asking for guidance in understanding this.
Thanks!

Comment: (1) You have a male staff member named Alice?  Interesting.  (2) You might get better results if you explained more plainly and clearly what you want.  Imagine that you’re trying to explain it to a nine-year-old.  What, exactly, do you mean by “google authentication”?  Do you want “bob” to be able to become super user by typing `su -` or `su root` *and **no password**?*  What password do you want him (or her?) to type? (3) Why are you not using `sudo`?

Comment: Sorry for my bad English. Ofc, i mean **google authenticator** to using with pam.d service to only for one user after using the su - or su root command. You're right, because bob does not have a password for su, he has to have time based codes (auth codes).

Comment: when bob typing su -or su root , I would like it to look like this: ```[bob@proxy ~]# su - $ Verification code:``` but alice will use the normal password ```[alice@proxy ~]# su - $ Password:```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pam_succeed_if](https://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_succeed_if) to skip the check as bob in `/etc/pam.d/su`, e.g.

```
auth [success=2 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so use_uid user in bob
auth sufficient                 pam_unix.so
auth requisite                  pam_deny.so
auth sufficient                 pam_google_authenticator.so
auth requisite                  pam_deny.so
```